# Getting a Intermittent issue while running Delete or Update in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, tez

I have a very strange behavior with my cluster, I am running Delete/Update statement in Hive cli which sometime works fine and some time fails below is the Command. **Table is ACID enabled**.

```
hive> delete from temptable where name='Jose';
```

Exception is as follows:

```css
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_15217_3223)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1                 FAILED     -1          0        0       -1       0       0
Reducer 2             KILLED      2          0        0        2       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 0.23 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_15217_3223_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_15217_3223_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: offset initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1514368279217_3223_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:155)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:273)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1268)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSargColumnNames(OrcInputFormat.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.setSearchArgument(OrcInputFormat.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:1011)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.access$2000(OrcInputFormat.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:992)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:989)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:838)
        ... 4 more
]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_15217_3223_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_15217_3223_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_15217_3223_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_15217_3223_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: offset initializer failed, vertex=vertex_15217_3223_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:155)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:273)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1268)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSargColumnNames(OrcInputFormat.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.setSearchArgument(OrcInputFormat.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:1011)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.access$2000(OrcInputFormat.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:992)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:989)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:838)
        ... 4 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_15217_3223_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_15217_3223_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
```

Unable to find any Solution.

What is the cause, Do I need to enable something or do I need to verify any config or missing something in the cli?

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the memory that is being used to run the query. Could be it is running out of memory allocation before it can finish the query. Also try using Tez, I find it normally runs faster... explanation between the two can be found here 
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/83394/difference-between-mr-and-tez.html

try setting these values(increase the memory based off of need) before you run your query

```
SET hive.tez.container.size=4096;
SET hive.tez.java.opts='-Xmx2000m';
SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

or these two if you're set on using mapreduce

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb 
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

Comment: Same Error After Executing these Values.

Comment: I suspect that error is Due to memory we have ample of memory more over if u see the stacktrace main reason looks to be, Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Answer (score 0):

Set execution engine to MR and try. I will work as expected.